# How to fix Euro/€ Symbole in TCPDF?

Tags: pdf, cell, tcpdf, euro

How to fix the Euro symbole within the "cell" function in TCPDF? "¤/" <--- This is what we get

```
$this->Cell(0, $this->rowHeight(), $data, 0, 1, 'L');
```

Comment: Does the symbol come out correctly if you use the Write() method?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this problem is already solved, but it may be caused by HTML encoding.
Either use

`utf8_encode()` or `utf8_decode()`

Otherwise, use this

`mb_convert_encoding(utf8_encode(<YOURCONTENT>), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');`

Comment: Thanks for contributing. It is already solved. The problem was the encoding.